# How to find Deprecated Alternatives in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

In Visual Studio we can easily find the alternative of deprecated class in the warning window. But how can I find the Deprecated alternative in Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alternatives are usually (90%) specified in the javadoc.

```
/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 * @deprecated This is deprecated. Use Muffins
 *
 */
@Deprecated
public class NotMuffins
{

}
```

My favorite solution? Google. ;-)

Comment: Means we will not able to find alternative in EClipse IDE. Thanks.

Comment: Can I check this in EClipse. When I click ctr + click , I get source not found

Comment: @user960567 There should be a button to set the source path under the "Source not found" message. Attach the src.zip in your Java JDK folder as External File. To see the Javadoc you can open the Javadoc View in Eclipse.

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen That's a totally different question, but yes: you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

Read documentation about it. There isn't any other way.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

P.s. JavaDocs not always suggest good choices.